# How the catalog:product:attributes:clean works?

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, cli, command-line

I have used the below command in Magento CLI,

```
php bin/magento catalog:product:attributes:clean
```

I read the description for this command in forums and stack overflow, they only say **Removes unused product attributes** but I need an example for a **real-time process**. Because it did not affect any **product attributes**.

Comment: This will help you out. https://www.atwix.com/magento/removing-needless-product-attribute-values/

Answer (score 0):

Enter the following command  : `php bin/magento`, you will see all the commands with theire description

[image]

`php bin/magento catalog:product:attributes:cleanup`  `=>` `Removes unused product attributes.`

See : `vendor\magento\module-catalog\Console\Command\ProductAttributesCleanUp.php::execute()`

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $output->setDecorated(true);
        $this->appState->setAreaCode(\Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_GLOBAL);
        $connection = $this->attributeResource->getConnection();
        $attributeTables = $this->getAttributeTables();

        $progress = new \Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\ProgressBar($output, count($attributeTables));
        $progress->setFormat('<comment>%message%</comment> %current%/%max% [%bar%] %percent:3s%% %elapsed%');

        $this->attributeResource->beginTransaction();
        try {
            // Find and remove unused attributes
            foreach ($attributeTables as $attributeTable) {
                $progress->setMessage($attributeTable . ' ');
                $affectedIds = $this->getAffectedAttributeIds($connection, $attributeTable);
                if (count($affectedIds) > 0) {
                    $connection->delete($attributeTable, ['value_id in (?)' => $affectedIds]);
                }
                $progress->advance();
            }
            $this->attributeResource->commit();

            $output->writeln("");
            $output->writeln("<info>Unused product attributes successfully cleaned up:</info>");
            $output->writeln("<comment>  " . implode("\n  ", $attributeTables) . "</comment>");
            return \Magento\Framework\Console\Cli::RETURN_SUCCESS;
        } catch (\Exception $exception) {
            $this->attributeResource->rollBack();

            $output->writeln("");
            $output->writeln("<error>{$exception->getMessage()}</error>");
            // we must have an exit code higher than zero to indicate something was wrong
            return \Magento\Framework\Console\Cli::RETURN_FAILURE;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yea, we can all see what it says it does, but what does it actually.... because it looks like it does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

When removing a store to a product. The data of that product store view are not deleted in these tables. I'm not yet sure why.

- catalog_product_entity_varchar
- catalog_product_entity_text
- catalog_product_entity_decimal
- catalog_product_entity_datetime
- catalog_product_entity_int

You **may** encounter issues like when filtering in product grid.

In our case. set filter status = 'Enabled'. but you will see some rows that have status = 'disabled'. the reason is, it is enabled to the store you deleted which needs to be cleanup. "Magento 2.3.4"

This is where this command comes in:

```
php bin/magento catalog:product:attributes:clean
```

This will clean the tables. So that grid filter will work as expected.

I think grid filter will not only be the issue, I hope this gives some idea.