# Magento 2 : Which SQL query will be executed in attributes clean console command?

Tags: magento2.3, query, console

Does any one know which sql query will be executed while running below console command?

```
$ php bin/magento catalog:product:attributes:cleanup
```

Comment: Refer this if that's relevant to you **https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/255629/how-the-catalogproductattributesclean-works**